# Can Tor be configured to run on all outgoing connections on a server?

Tags: server-administration

I want to make a web-service that is going to make requests to various other servers. However, I don't want those servers to be able to pinpoint the location/IP address of my service (As a SPAM prevention method, along with other things).

I was wondering if it's possible to set a server box (Be it dedicated or VPS, with a popular linux distro) to run all outgoing connections via Tor (ideally silently and separately from the service that makes the requests).

The end result should be that using a simple cURL or other HTTP requests from the server would run through Tor and as such would be anonymized.

---

Is this possible? Am I barking up the wrong tree? If it is, could you provide with pointers/articles that can help me implement this?

> <sub>Note: This is all still theoretical. I don't have the server or the service yet, so I can implement it in any way I need for this to work.</sub>

Comment: I don't care how it's done as long as the target server sees an IP address different from my own. It's a form of security by obscurity (I don't make the rules, sadly). I'm looking for the simplest way to setup, and ideally, the one that takes the least tinkering afterwards.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Follow the guide in Tor wiki for 'Transparently Doing DNS and Routing for .onion Traffic' here:

https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/wiki/doc/TransparentProxy

substitute the Ip in the guide with your own local IP.
I've been using it many times on Debian and ubuntu to route all traffic on the machine through tor, works great.

Comment: The guide says it's for onion traffic only, I want **all** traffic, is it possible?

Comment: Scroll down and follow ' Local Redirection Through Tor' guide. Routes everything through it. I tested it on debian. Important step is IP and the uid number for the tor user make sure to get that correct.

Comment: Where do I input my IP address? I don't see anything related to it there... Could you perhaps [edit] your answer to include those details?

Comment: Yup, Local Redirection Through Tor did the trick. Although I never had to change any IP address