# Tor sometimes manages to connect, sometimes couldn't resolve host

Tags: server-administration

This is a followup of [Can Tor be configured to run on all outgoing connections on a server?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/q/1601/521)

I've successfully placed Tor as a transparent proxy over my VPS, however, I'm getting some trouble.

I am trying with

```
curl http://icanhazip.com
```

Sometimes, it returns an IP which is different from the original one of the server. Sometimes however, it returns "Couldn't resolve host".

It seems as though every once in a while, if I wait, then curl, it would give the error, and subsequent calls would return an IP like intended.

What could be the cause? How can I further debug this?

---

```
curl -v icanhazip.com
```

Gives me the following:

```
* getaddrinfo(3) failed for icanhazip.com:80
* Couldn't resolve host 'icanhazip.com'
* Closing connection #0
curl: (6) Couldn't resolve host 'icanhazip.com'
```

Comment: Which side is the Tor on of the VPS?

Comment: @Cammy_the_block: What do you mean? Tor is sitting as a service, and all outgoing requests are supposed to be routed through it (and they are). I don't understand what you mean by "what side" though.

Comment: You said "I've successfully placed Tor as a transparent proxy over my VPS". Does that mean that you are routing traffic over your VPS then through Tor or visa versa?

Comment: @Cammy I'm sending request from my VPS to 3rd party services. I'm routing those through tor.

Comment: Did it work before you were routing Tor traffic through a VPS?

Comment: @Cammy yes, when I clear all of the iptable rules it works, and I get the VPS original IP

Comment: So it works when sending traffic straight to the VPS? Does it work just using a standard Tor config?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `curl -v icanhazip.com` and play with `--connect-timeout --max-time --retry-max-time`. +

Comment: I've added the information to the question. It seems as though the other parameters you mentioned have no effect.

Comment: Try curl -v --socks5-hostname localhost:9050 http://icanhazip.com

Comment: I get this: http://pastie.org/9308770

Comment: It worked, you can see the resolved IP at the bottom :)